# Django BaseController

Tags: python, django, laravel

A working example of mine, trying to streamlining my Django views, with absolute inspiration from Laravel:

```
class BaseController(View):
    template_404 = "404.html"

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.view(*args, **kwargs)

    def view(self, request, slug=None):
        method = request.method.lower()
        if hasattr(self, method):
            return getattr(self, method)(request, slug)
        return self.forbidden(request)

    def get(self, request, slug):
        if slug is not None:
            return getattr(self, "show")(request, slug) if hasattr(self, "index") else self.forbidden(request)
        return getattr(self, "index")(request) if hasattr(self, "index") else self.forbidden(request)

    def post(self, request, slug):
        return getattr(self, "store")(request) if hasattr(self, "store") else self.forbidden(request)

    @staticmethod
    def forbidden(request):
        return HttpResponseForbidden("Method not allowed")

    def page_not_found(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_404)
```

Inherited by:

```
class EulerController(BaseController):
    template_name_index = "euler_index.html"
    template_name_show = "euler_show.html"

    def index(self, request):
        euler_posts = EulerPost.objects.all()
        return render(request, self.template_name_index, {"euler_posts": euler_posts})

    def show(self, request, slug):
        euler_post = EulerPost.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
        return render(request, self.template_name_show, {"euler_post": euler_post})
```

and called by:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', EulerController(), name='main'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', EulerController(), name='resource'),
]
```

and the mock model:

```
class EulerPost(model):
    slug = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)
```

I left Django for PHP-Laravel, long ago believing myself to be an to unstructured for the freedom of Django.  But now I feel I am on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually better to ask forgiveness than permission and explicit is better than implicit. So I would change your `getattr..if hasattr` to a `try..except`, which is a lot easier to understand:

```
def post(self, request, slug):
    try:
        return self.store(request)
    except AttributeError:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden("Method not allowed")
```

And similar for `get` and `view`:

```
def get(self, request, slug):
    try:
        if slug is not None:
            return self.show(request, slug)
        return self.index(request)
    except AttributeError:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden("Method not allowed")

def view(self, request, slug=None):
    try:
        return getattr(self, request.method.lower())(request, slug)
    except AttributeError:
        raise HttpResponseForbidden("Method not allowed")
```